# Arithmetic mean in java

Tags: java

**Problem statement**

Need to find the Arithmetic mean of numbers entered by user.

**Constraints**

- We cannot ask user to define/share the number of "NUMBERS" user has planned to enter i.e. we cannot ask user to tell how many numbers he is going to enter.
- If -1 is entered by user, the input should stop and Arithmetic mean should be displayed.
- We are supposed to ask user only to enter the numbers for which Arithmetic mean is to be calculated. Like : User enters 
  2
  4
  7
  10
  -1 
  so we need to calculate arithmetic mean for 2,4,7,10 and display the result.

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Value is :" + n);
        count++;
        sum = sum + n;  
    }while ( n != -1);

}
```

It goes to infinite loop and I've also tried using if/else but i didn't work. Please assist.

For the input of :

```
3
9
4
-7
0
2
-1
```

The arithmetic mean should be calculated for 3,9,4,7,0,2,29 i.e. 1.8

Comment: You need to redefine `n` in each iteration or your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int n = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter next number(-1 to exit): ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Value is :" + n);

        if(n != -1)
        {
            count++;
            sum = sum + n; 
        }

    }while ( n != -1);

    sc.close();
    System.out.println("Mean is: " + (double) sum/count);
}
```

You needed to move your `sc.nextInt();` into the loop so that you can keep entering in values.  I also added an `if` statement so the `-1` does not get used in the mean value.

Comment: You need to cast `sum` and/or `count` to `double`, otherwise you're doing integer division (truncating the result to a whole number).

Answer (score 0):

You're reading "n" as input out of the while, then n has always the first value and the loop is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep passing ints, otherwise n is forever the first value entered.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
int sum = 0; 
do { 
    System.out.println("Value is :" + n); 
    count++;
    sum = sum + n;
    n = sc.nextInt();
}while ( n != -1);
```